# Print numbers from file, from x to y

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I've got a file with numbers from -100 to 100, I only want to print from -10 to 10

Currently, I'm at

```
egrep '[0-9][0-3]'
```

Which, unfortunately, prints -13, -12, -11, -10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23.

Comment: Why [0-3] and not [0-9]?

Comment: did you mean egrep '[0-9][0-9]?'

Comment: Ah, threw in the wrong command, it was supposed to be [0-9][0-9], this was an experiment (a bad one) to get a better understand of what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with that regular expression:

```
^[-]?(10|[0-9])$
```

So the call on CLI would be:

```
egrep "^[-]?(10|[0-9])$" testfile
```

---

*Why?*

- start with an optional leading "-"
- followed by either:

  - literal number "10" or
  - single digit between 0 and 9
- and nothing behind that

Comment: Awesome! And thanks a lot for the explanation too! Now I'm curious how I'd got to do the same thing but from a different range, eg. -8 to 25?

Comment: Ah, think I figured out it.

egrep '^(-8|[0-9]|10[0-9]|20[0-5])' numbers.txt

*edit* - It's printing all from 0 to 23 but only -8 and not numbers from -8 to 0.

Comment: assuming you just need ranges you can use the seq command which will generate a sequence for example seq -8 1 23 = all numbers between -8 to 23

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep '^-?10$|^-?[0-9]$'
```

this is basically two regexs one to get 10,-10 and one to get all the singular numbers

Comment: Any idea how to do from a different range, eg. -8 to 25?

Answer (score 0):

This is not about egrep, since from your comments it seems you don't want egrep for its own sake here are some alternatives:

1. use seq: `seq first inc last`

   `seq -15 1 14` will print all numbers between -15 to 14 each on his own line
2. use awk: `awk '{ if ($1 >= first && $1 <= last) print $1 }' filename`

   `awk '{ if ($1 >= -15 && $1 <= 14) print $1 }' numbers.txt` will print all numbers between -15 to 14 each on his own line
3. use perl: `perl -lane 'print $_ if $_ >= first && $_ <= last' filename`

   `perl -lane 'print $_ if $_ >= -15 && $_ <= 14' numbers.txt` will print all lines between -15 to 14 each on his own line

hope it helps