# Linux grep - print numbers from file in x to y

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I just asked how to print from -10 and 10, although I understand it now, I have no understanding how I could print from a different range, eg. from -8 to 23.

What I first did

```
egrep '^-?[0-8]?[0]?[1-9]$' numbers.txt
```

Prints from -24 to 24

```
egrep '^[-]?[0-8]$+\.?' numbers.txt
```

Prints from -8 to 8.

How could I combine each other so the result would be -8 .. 23?

Comment: add a link to the question. Note: use `|`

Comment: Pardon, original question

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758414/print-numbers-from-file-from-x-to-y/33758676#33758676)

Comment: In your other question, you say the file has numbers -100 to 100; are there 201 lines in that file, the first line containing -100 and the last line 100? If so, there is a better way than using grep.

Comment: The new file only contains -100, -24 .. 24, 100 for convenience, every time I'd try a command it would be overwhelming.

The command I'm trying out now is 
     
          egrep '^-?[0-8]?[0]?[1-9]$' numbers.txt

and the result is -24 to 24 (not including -100 or 100).

Comment: grep is the wrong tool for the job. Perhaps you want to `sort` the lines and then run `awk` to print those from -8 to 23?

Comment: super-easy general-purpose way that doesn't use a regex: `awk '(-100 <= $1) && ($1 <= 100)'`.  The `{print}` is implicit, so this awk program is *just* a rule that checks the first field of a line.  awk is pretty lightweight, and starts up nearly as fast as grep (unlike the much heavier weight perl or python interpreters).  Leaving this as a comment, since the regex hackery needed could be useful in a context where you're limited to regexes, and can't just use other tools in the command-line toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can for example say:

```
egrep '^(-?0?[0-8]|9|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$'
```

This uses a `^(option1|option2|...|option_n)$` to match the following cases:

- `-?0?[0-8]` -8 to 8
- `9` 9
- `1[0-9]` 10 to 19
- `2[0-3]` 20 to 23

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this was far away from what I'd attempted but I think I'm getting a better understanding on this.

Comment: The `1.` part may also capture `1x`, `1$` or even `1§` for example, if you want to make sure it only captures digits you have to specify it in the following manner: `1[0-9]` or as a complete expression: `'^(-?0?[0-8]|9|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$'`

Comment: @Yaron you are right. I was a bit lazy assuming all data is just digits. Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
egrep --color '[-][1-8]|([0]|[1])[0-9]|[2][0-3]'
```

`[-][1-8]` # -1 to -8

`([0]|[1])[0-9]` # 0-19

`[2][0-3]` #20-23

Comment: Depending on the formatting of the file, you might want to add an `-x` option.  If the OP's input file contains `100`, that will contain `10`, which matches your regex.